# How to connect my Windows phone to TV?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, television

Thanks in advance..

I have a windows phone application. In that I am showing some images in an `Image` control. I need to connect my phone to a tv and show the image on tv screen. How can I connect my phone to tv and display the image in television?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: @ Robaticus - Yes, it is. I need to connect the phone to tv and show some specific part of my current display in tv. This should be done from my program. This is for showing a presentation on tv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a current option for sharing WP7 screen in the OS itself. So you would have to write a relatively big peace of software to do that. And you have to verify that you TV has capabilities of accessing device and services on the network.

Comment: I have actually realised that LG phones has this features. I know LG Optimus does that.

Answer (score -3):

What you need is a cable for your computer to your tv conect a hdrm cable from asda tobtour laptop thwnnloadbrhe pictures to your laptop from your fone then fo into your tv settings and go into av channels that can display windows on your tv screen click devices and printers then click on the windows fone to display files or will spear on your tv in secconds